# Spark unable to extract rootTag eleement using spark-xml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I would like to extract rootTag element from xml file using Spark (spark-xml version 0.13.0 scala 2.11). But its unable to do so.
For example, xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <dt_creation>13-03-2023</dt_creation> 
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>
         Oracle Streams Advanced Queuing XMLType support.
      </description></book><book id="bk102">
      <price>5.95</price>
   </book>
 </catalog>
```

I would like to dt_creation field from rootTag using spark code like so:

```
val df = sparkSession.read
            .format("xml")
            .option("rootTag", "catalog")
            .option("rowTag", "book")
            .load(above-xml-file)

df.select("dt_creation").collect()
```

It leads to

> AnalysisException@12599 "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> cannot resolve '`dt_creation`' given input columns: [description,
> price, genre, publish_date, title, _id, author];; 'Project
> ['dt_creation]

How to really extract such rootTag elements which exists outside of rowTag?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible to get the rootTag attribute. Please refert to this issue : https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/503

Comment: Thanks! Then what would be the ideal way to parse such root elements along with rootTag? Create a separate read as textfile and then parse and extract root element?

Comment: I think that you have to figure out how you would like to have it in your dataframe. Remembre that you will have one line for each rowTag. Is means that you will duplicate your root attribute for all the lines of your dataframe. Is it good ? may be not. may be you can get these attributes using only scala xml and use them when needed ?